# Algorithm to choose multiple discrete parameters based on input vector

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

I am faced with the following problem: Given a point in *k*-dimensional space, choose a set of discrete parameters to maximize the probability of a positive (binary) outcome. I have training examples in the same form, for example

```
    point       parameters    good?
    ------      ----------    -----
1)  x1 x2 x3    p1 p2 p3      NO
2)  x1 x2 x3    p1 p2 p3      YES
3)  x1 x2 x3    p1 p2 p3      YES
    ...etc.
```

All parameters are free variables, and there is an arbitrary number of them (*k* is also arbitrary). I have considered

1. Generate a clustering of the points, tune the parameters for each cluster, and then associate each new point with a cluster.
2. Develop a model to predict each parameter separately.

Both have major drawbacks. I was wondering if there is a more systematic approach to going about this (seems like a common enough problem). Can anyone point me towards some relevant reading or an algorithm?

Thanks, and I apologize in advance if this is the wrong place to ask these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) (data mining) problem and it's up to you to pick which algorithm to use. The most common approaches are:

- [KNN (k-nearest-neighbor)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)
- [Bayes classifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier)
- [SVM (support vector machine)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)
- [Decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)

You should read up about them and decide which one is best for your problem, unfortunately there is no 'best' approach for all domains and data.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple technique you haven't mentioned is k-nearest neighbours - find the nearest positive point in k-dimensional space to your input point and copy its choice of parameters.

If you knew or could find out more about what the k-dimensional space or parameters actually mean, you might be able to use this knowledge to construct a good model.